# Turf.js with multiple webworkers for point transformation 48 core CPU

Tags: geojson, masking, turf

I need to split a GeoJSON file to multiple parts engaging about 10 web workers to do some point transformation using turf.js. Afterwards, the returned processed data will need to be appended to form the final masked GeoJSON.

I do know that we have to create the webworkers, split the GeoJSON into, say 10 chunks, and then send each of these chunks to each  webworkers to do the masking.

```
function createWorkers(workerCount, src) {
    var workers = new Array(workerCount);
    for (var i = 0; i < workerCount; i++) {
        workers[i] = new Worker(src);
    }
    return workers;
}
function doWork(worker, data) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        worker.onmessage = resolve;
        worker.postMessage(data);
    });
}
function doDistributedWork(workers, data) {
    // data size is always a multiple of the number of workers
    var elementsPerWorker = data.length / workers.length;
    return Promise.all(workers.map(function(worker, index) {
        var start = index * elementsPerWorker;
        return doWork(worker, data.slice(start, start+elementsPerWorker));
    }));
}

var myWebWorkers = createWorkers(8, 'worker.js');
var somedata = [...];
function step(i) {
    if (i <= 0)
        return Promise.resolve("done!");
    return doDistributedWork(myWebWorkers, somedata)
    .then(function(results) {
        if (i % 100)
            updateWebPage();
        return step(i-1)
    });
}
step(1000).then(console.log);
```

How I should split the GeoJSON into chunks and pass it to this worker.js, and once the point transformation is complete, combine the returned results back into a large GeoJSON?

Comment: Your question contains several questions, which is against GIS SE site policy of focused question. Please break it so simple focused questions and then post them on by one.

Comment: Why are you determined to do this in JavaScript rather than a language that supports parallelism?

Comment: I need this in javascript as the masking procedure is in javascript.
Also, the application needs to run in  web browser.

Comment: @TomazicM I have now made the question more focused.

Comment: Question is stall a way to complex. There is a bunch of code with no description of what this masking task is, what are inputs and what are outputs, is algorithm such that is independent for certain point on neighboring points, why is there reference to  https://github.com/TheTinHat/MaskMyXYZ/blob/master/assets/js/xyz.js, if you are using only part of the code and so on ...

Comment: @TomazicM, I have made the question more focussed. Added some starter code, and also remove the masking code.

Comment: You didn't answer any of my questions above, there is still reference to huge amount of outside code and so on. If you want to get an answer on GIS SE site, clearly describe masking task (what is it doing, input, output), is masking algorithm such that for certain point it is independent on neighboring points. Then divide you question to two parts and ask them separately: (1) how to divide GeoJSON for workers (2) how to create and use workers.

Comment: @TomazicM, done as you asked. Removed all questions related to masking and just asking about how to split the geoJSON. Now this should be easier.

Comment: You write "I do not know the following two things", which clearly states you still have two questions. Please limit your question to a single question. When this one is resolved, post next question as a separate question.

Comment: Changing only the form of the question but not the content does not help. There are still two questions: (1) how I should split the geojson into chunks and pass it to this worker.js and (2) once the point transformation is complete, combine the returned results back into a large geojson